# SQL/SqlAlchemy: Querying all objects in a dependancy tree

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table with a self, asymmetric many-to-many relationship of dependancies between objects. I use that relationship to create a dependably tree between objects.

Having a set of object IDs, I would like to fetch all objects that are somewhere in that dependancy tree.

Here's an example objects table:

```
+----+------+
| ID | Name |
+----+------+
|  1 |    A |
|  2 |    B |
|  3 |    C |
|  4 |    D |
|  5 |    E |
+----+------+
```

And a table of relationships:

```
+------------+-----------+
| Dependancy | Dependant |
+------------+-----------+
|          2 |         1 |
|          3 |         2 |
|          4 |         1 |
+------------+-----------+
```

Showing `A (ID: 1)` depends on both `B(2)` and `D(4)`, and that `B(2)` depends on `C(3)`.

Now, I would like to construct a single SQL query that given `{1}` as a set with a single ID will return the four objects in `A`'s dependancy tree: `A`, `B`, `D` and `C`.
Alternatively, using one query to fetch all needed object IDs and another to fetch their actual data is also acceptable.

This should be work regardless of the number of levels in the dependency/hierarchy tree.

I'll be happy with either an SQLAlchemy example or plain SQL for the  postgresql 10 database (which I'll see how to implement with SQLAlchemy later on).

Thanks!

Comment: What DB are you using, or in other words can you use recursive CTE?

Comment: I'm using postgresql version 10. I'm unfamiliar with recursive CTE but that's a great pointer, I'll read up on that!